# simple_form error notifications not displaying using zurb foundation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, simple-form, zurb-foundation

I am using Zurb Foundation and Simple form

```
<%= simple_form_for @complaint do |f| %>
   <%= f.error_notification %>

   <%= f.association :company, as: :radio, label: false %>
   <%= f.input :country, priority: ["United States"] %>
   <%= f.input :city %>
   <%= f.input :client, placeholder: 'Coca-Cola' %>
   <%= f.input :body %>

   <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

In my model:

```
class Complaint < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  attr_accessible :body, :city, :client, :country, :company_id
  validates :company, presence: { message: 'Company cannot be blank!' }
  validates :body, presence: true
  validates :country, presence: true
  validates :city, presence: true
end
```

When I click submit on an empty form I expect to have errors saying 'Company cannot be blank!' etc.

Am I using `<%= f.error_notification %>` incorrectly?
How can I get there to show errors?

Answer (score 0):

Don't take this as verbatim since I'm only a few months into rails myself, but I don't think error_notification is intended to display the errors :- the errors themselves are intended to be displayed alongside the component. HOWEVER I have a situation where using f.input_field the f.error field alongside the component is messy so I wanted all my errors at the top of the page so I created a simple partial:

```
-if object.errors.any?
  .alert{:class => "alert-error"}
    %p= "Please correct the following #{pluralize(object.errors.count, 'error')}:"
    %ul
      - object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
        %li= msg
```

and rendered it at the top of the page:

```
= render "layouts/errors", :object => @booking
```

Sorry, haml. The

```
  .alert{:class => "alert-error"}
```

styles it just the same as the notification.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please show your controller CREATE action code. I had a similar error and the problem was there.

**You might have used @complaint.save! instead of just @complaint.save**

You should call save instead of save! so the if statement can fail, your object will contain messages in its errors object, and simple_form can render them next to each form input after render :new.

Comment: Sorry I am no longer working on that repo and dont have the controller code.